# Accessing elements in a list of arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, printing

```
c = []
Indices = []
list_ = iter([0.10,0.16,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.90])
for i in list_:
    b = around((total_*i), decimals = 2)
    t = where(fcol == find_nearest(fcol,b))
    c.append(b)
    indices.append(t)
    print t #gives:

(array([485]),)
(array([523]),)
(array([576]),)
(array([733]),)
(array([963]),)
(array([1254]),)
```

when I print the indices list outside for loop it looks like:

```
print indices #gives:    
[(array([485]),), (array([523]),), (array([576]),), (array([733]),), (array([963]),), (array([1254]),)]
```

While desired output is a list like:

```
[485, 523, 576, 733, 963, 1254]
```

**Question:**
Is this method I used to write a 'list of arrays' a good approach?(well I think there may be more efficient ways) If it is, how can I access the numbers (elements of arrays) in the list?

Comment: You're applying `type` to `indices` (lowercase), which is not the same thing as `Indices` (uppercase), which the first code snippet uses.  Be consistent.

Comment: An easy way to avoid this error is to follow the python convention and have all variables be lowercase.

Comment: @SethMMorton, thanks for your comment. I edited my question for that, but the main question still remains. Any ideas about that?

Comment: Why the weird call to `iter` instead of iterating over the list directly?

Comment: Good point! I had added that iter before the list for some reason which I don't remember now, but it's working fine without that! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
indices.append(list(t[0])) 
    #which gives:    
[[485], [523], [576], [733], [963], [1254]]
```

and then:

```
for x in indices:
    print (x[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You've likely created an `indices` function elsewhere.

```
>>> Indices = []
>>> type(Indices)
<type 'list'>
```

So you need to be careful about capitalization.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I edited my question and removed the silly part about type!